# How to use Drawer Navigator & Stack Navigator combined in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

**Packages Used:**

1. "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
2. "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
3. "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",

**Problem :**

**Image 1,2 & 3:** I have implemented drawer which shows two option as HomePage and Terms & Condition. If you click on t&c option it opens its screen and same if you click on homescreen it goes back to homepage screen.

**Image 1 & 4:** I have made "Click for details page" text as clickable on HomeScreen and after I click it should go to details screen but throws error as image 4 I am confused on how to implement it. Where do I write Stack.Navigation code.

[image]

App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen';
import DetailPage from './Screens/DetailPage';
import TermsCondition from './Screens/TermsCondition';


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
        <Drawer.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Term&Condition" component={TermsCondition} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

HomeScreen.js

```
export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DetailPage')}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 50 }}>Click for Details Page</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

TermsCondition.js

```
function TermsCondition({ navigation}) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:50}}>T&C Page</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  export default TermsCondition;
```

DetailPage.js

```
function DetailPage({ navigation}) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:50}}>DetailPage</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

export default DetailPage;
Sorry for this silly question but I tried it online but confused a lot.
Thank You in advance!

Comment: Try using nesting navigators method: read this- 'https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#passing-params-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator'

Comment: Where is 'DetailPage' ? in your posted code there is no page with 'DetailPage' name

Comment: It was just a normal code so didnt include it but added it.

Comment: @JohnOcean I will try it out

Comment: Could you share App.js fully?

Comment: @CoreSphinx Done !!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was simple step of [Nested Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#passing-params-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator)
Here is the solution for the same:

**App.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen';
import DetailPage from './Screens/DetailPage';
import TermsCondition from './Screens/TermsCondition';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';



const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

{/* Add Drawer.Navigation to a function.*/}
function Root() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Term&Condition" component={TermsCondition} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen options={{
        }} name="Root" component={Root} {/*Call function as Stack.Screen*/}
        options={{ headerShown: false }} /> {/*This will disable function header*/}
        <Stack.Screen options={{
          title: 'DetailPage'
        }} name="DetailPage" component={DetailPage} />
      </Stack.Navigator>

    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**Note:** Rest All the code for DetailPage.js, HomeScreen.js,TermCondition.js is same.

Ps. Take some break from the error and return back with fresh mind. that might solve it:-)